# Difference between projectslocation and projectszone functions/types in go sdk of google cloud

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, sdk, gcloud

Going through the container [package](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/container/v1) for the go cloud sdk, one sees that there are mainly 2 distinct type of types and methods when it comes to available resources:

- projectslocation, e.g. [ProjectsLocationsClustersCreateCall](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/container/v1#ProjectsLocationsClustersCreateCall)
- projectszone e.g.  [ProjectsZonesClustersAddonsCall](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/container/v1#ProjectsZonesClustersAddonsCall)

What is their difference?

just for the record, I am looking for the pattern that one has to follow so that

a) it passes (in some method?) the project id

b) it retrieves all the available GKE clusters belonging to that project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `container/v1` Go APIs are generated from the underlying Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) REST APIs ([public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/)), which provide support for querying clusters either by *zone* or by *location*. Inspecting those docs, you will find most recommendations are to use the locations API. Although the zone-specific APIs remain available for backwards compatibility, any filtering by zone, for example, is deprecated:

[image: Screenshot of Google Kubernetes Engine REST API v1 projects.zones.clusters.list endpoint docs, showing the zone parameter is deprecated.]

From memory, I believe the ability to search for clusters by *location* was added when support for *regional* GKE clusters was announced; the control plane for such clusters is shared across multiple zones for high availability purposes and an API was provided which generalises over both zonal and regional clusters.

---

In order to obtain all clusters in a project via an API call, as per your request, you can use the `location` field of the `(*container.ProjectsLocationsClustersService).List` method to make such a call of the underlying APIs:

```golang
projectID := "my-project-id" // TODO fill in project ID
svc, err := container.NewService(context.TODO())
// TODO: handle err
parent := fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/locations/-", projectID) // Location "-" matches all zones and regions
resp, err := svc.Projects.Locations.Clusters.List(parent).Do()
// TODO do something with response and error
```

More details of the structure of the `parent` parameter and the behaviour of the List call is [available in the API docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters/list).

The zonal API will provide support for listing regional clusters when queried for all zones (setting the `zone` parameter to `-`). However, as it only accepts zone arguments as filters in its List method, it offers no functionality for filtering regional clusters in a specific region. Other endpoints of the same API have a similar limitation.